# Need to click twice on NSTextField to become active

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, first-responder, mousedown

I have an NSTextField which is by default non editable and is first responder.
I would like to make the NSTextField editable/active as soon as I click on it.
I subclassed it and used the mousedown event:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"link mouse down");

    [self setEditable:TRUE];
}
```

However I need to click 2 times on the NSTextFIeld to become active and editable, but for each click I can properly see the NSLog "Mouse down".
Anything I forgot to do ? Thanks

Comment: That's totally normal behavior afaik. It works just the same way as in Finder when you click on a filename to edit it.

Comment: Thanks. And if I wanted to achieve what I want, what would be the way around ?

Comment: Sure it's a double-click and not the common click-delay (again, as in Finder) that'll activate the text field..?

Answer (score 1):

In your `NSTextField` subclass, try overriding [-acceptsFirstMouse:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BCIDIGDA) and returning `YES`. Get rid of your `-mouseDown:` override, though.